# CakePhp3 Meta description

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I wanted to ask, if there is a way to assign meta description tag from view file ?
I know, that this code inside my .ctp file will work fine:

```
// Assign title tag
$this->assign('title','Page title);
```

I have tried :

```
$this->Html->assing('description','description']);
```

But without success.

Or, if this is not possible, how set meta description, but not from layout?
This works, but only in layout view file:

```
<?= $this->Html->meta(
    'description',
    'enter any meta description here'
);?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `block` option for the `meta()` function (http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.View.Helper.HtmlHelper.html#_meta)

```
<?php $this->Html->meta(
    'description',
    'enter any meta description here',
    ['block' => 'meta']
);?>
```

And then echo the `meta` block in your layout:

```
<?= $this->fetch('meta'); ?>
```